# How to make a countdown timer in Android?

Tags: android, timer, countdown

I have two EditTexts in XML. In one EditText, the user can put a number as minutes and in another EditText, a number as seconds. After clicking the finish button, the seconds EditText should start to countdown and update its text every second.

Additionally, how can I keep it updating until it gets to zero minutes and zero seconds?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android countdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10010684/android-countdown)

Answer (score 525, accepted):

As shown in [the documentation for `CountDownTimer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer#java):

> ```java
> new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
>
>     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
>         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
>         // logic to set the EditText could go here
>     }
>
>     public void onFinish() {
>         mTextField.setText("done!");
>     }
>
> }.start();
> ```

Comment: This is a nice answer but can anyone show me how to do a custom set countdown time rather than just inputting 30 seconds? I tried getting the value from an EditText but it didn't seem to work at all.

Comment: What if I wanted to base the CountDownTimer on a set alarm? How do I know how many milisUntilFinished?

Comment: Do you know if there is a pause method for the `countdowntimer`? So say the user wanted to pause a game they clicked a button and the countdown timer is paused and when they click play it keeps on ticking?

Comment: What will happen if i set timer for 24h for example everything is working fine but user changes his device time How to Avoid that?

Answer (score 128):

if you use the below code (as mentioned in accepted answer),

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
       //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        mTextField.setText("done!");
    }

}.start();
```

It will result in memory leak of the instance of the activity where you use this code, if you don't carefully clean up the references.

use the following code

```
//Declare timer
CountDownTimer cTimer = null;

//start timer function
void startTimer() {
    cTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        }
        public void onFinish() {
        }
    };
    cTimer.start();
}


//cancel timer
void cancelTimer() {
    if(cTimer!=null)
        cTimer.cancel();
}
```

You need to call **cTtimer.cancel()** whenever the **onDestroy()/onDestroyView()** in the owning Activity/Fragment is called.

Comment: Yes! 10/10. this should be correct answer. OR else even though you press BACK, the countDownThread is very much working. You can place a Log.i, and you will see it throwing up info every 1sec, if you dont put a ".cancel()".

Comment: is there a way to check if the CountDownTiner is still running before cancelling?

Comment: check if timer is !=null

Comment: What will happen if i set timer for 24h for example everything is working fine but user changes his device time How to Avoid that? @AbdulrahmanAbdelkader

Answer (score 66):

[image]

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.zeustechnocrats.countdown;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private String EVENT_DATE_TIME = "2023-12-31 10:30:00";
    private String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
    private LinearLayout linear_layout_1, linear_layout_2;
    private TextView tv_days, tv_hour, tv_minute, tv_second;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Runnable runnable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.count_down);

        initUI();
        countDownStart();
    }

    private void initUI() {
        linear_layout_1 = findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_1);
        linear_layout_2 = findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_2);
        tv_days = findViewById(R.id.tv_days);
        tv_hour = findViewById(R.id.tv_hour);
        tv_minute = findViewById(R.id.tv_minute);
        tv_second = findViewById(R.id.tv_second);
    }

    private void countDownStart() {
        runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
                    Date event_date = dateFormat.parse(EVENT_DATE_TIME);
                    Date current_date = new Date();
                    if (!current_date.after(event_date)) {
                        long diff = event_date.getTime() - current_date.getTime();
                        long Days = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
                        long Hours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
                        long Minutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
                        long Seconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
                        //
                        tv_days.setText(String.format("%02d", Days));
                        tv_hour.setText(String.format("%02d", Hours));
                        tv_minute.setText(String.format("%02d", Minutes));
                        tv_second.setText(String.format("%02d", Seconds));
                    } else {
                        linear_layout_1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        linear_layout_2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_event"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:text="Android Event Start"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_days"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="00"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_days_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Days"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_hour"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="00"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_hour_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Hour"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_minute"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="00"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_minute_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Minute"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_second"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="00"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_second_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Second"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why `handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1 * 1000);` ??

Comment: Do not forget to clean the timer once the activity is destroyed. Otherwise you will sendup with memory leak

Comment: handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0) = handler.post(runnable)

Comment: excellent solutions if anybody wants to add time zone try this dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+05:30"));

Answer (score 47):

just copy paste the following code........

**MainActivity**

package com.example.countdowntimer;

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


      TextView text1;

 private static final String FORMAT = "%02d:%02d:%02d";

 int seconds , minutes;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    new CountDownTimer(16069000, 1000) { // adjust the milli seconds here

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            text1.setText(""+String.format(FORMAT,
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(
                      TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));              
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            text1.setText("done!");
        }
     }.start();             

  }

  }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: but when my mobile locked its paused and when i unlocked it will resume..what can i do for continues timer ??

Comment: Please do not encourage copy pasting of code. A link to documentation and explanation would have been a better answer.

Answer (score 23):

**Just Call below function by passing seconds and textview object**

```
public void reverseTimer(int Seconds,final TextView tv){

    new CountDownTimer(Seconds* 1000+1000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            int minutes = seconds / 60;
            seconds = seconds % 60;
            tv.setText("TIME : " + String.format("%02d", minutes)
                    + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds));
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            tv.setText("Completed");
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Comment: Perfect case to catch NPE.
What happens when activity is destroyed and timer remains running?

Answer (score 13):

Revers CountDown timer with hours minutes and seconds

```
public void reverseTimer(int Seconds, final TextView tv) {

    new CountDownTimer(Seconds * 1000 + 1000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);

            int hours = seconds / (60 * 60);
            int tempMint = (seconds - (hours * 60 * 60));
            int minutes = tempMint / 60;
            seconds = tempMint - (minutes * 60);

            tv.setText("TIME : " + String.format("%02d", hours)
                    + ":" + String.format("%02d", minutes)
                    + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds));
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            tv.setText("Completed");
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Using Kotlin:

```
var timer = object: CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            tvTimer.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000)
        }

        override fun onFinish() {
            tvTimer.setText("done!")
        }
    }
timer.start()
```

Answer (score 7):

Output: 01:30

```
new CountDownTimer(90000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long duration) {
                //tTimer.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext resource id
                // Duration
                long Mmin = (duration / 1000) / 60;
                long Ssec = (duration / 1000) % 60;
                if (Ssec < 10) {
                    tTimer.setText("" + Mmin + ":0" + Ssec);
                } else tTimer.setText("" + Mmin + ":" + Ssec);
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                tTimer.setText("00:00");
            }

        }.start();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Scan extends AppCompatActivity {
int minute;
long min;
TextView tv_timer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan2);
    tv_timer=findViewById(R.id.tv_timer);
    minute=Integer.parseInt("Your time in string form like 10");
    min= minute*60*1000;
    counter(min);
}
private void counter(long min) {
    CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(min, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            int seconds = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60;
            int minutes = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
            int hours = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
            tv_timer.setText(String.format("%d:%d:%d", hours, minutes, seconds));
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your time has been completed",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

```
var futureMinDate = Date()
val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH)
try {
    futureMinDate = sdf.parse("2019-08-22")
} catch (e: ParseException) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}

// Here futureMinDate.time Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GM
// So we need to subtract the millis from current millis to get actual millis
object : CountDownTimer(futureMinDate.time - System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000) {
    override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
        val sec = (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60
        val min = (millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60)) % 60
        val hr = (millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24
        val day = ((millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60 * 60)) / 24).toInt()
        val formattedTimeStr = if (day > 1) "$day days $hr : $min : $sec"
        else "$day day $hr : $min : $sec"
        tvFlashDealCountDownTime.text = formattedTimeStr
    }

    override fun onFinish() {
        tvFlashDealCountDownTime.text = "Done!"
    }
}.start()
```

Pass a future date and convert it to milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

The Interface way.

```
import android.os.CountDownTimer;

/**
 * Created by saikiran on 07-03-2016.
 */
public class CountDownTimerCustom extends CountDownTimer {

    private TimeTickListener mTickListener;
    private TimeFinishListener mFinishListener;
    private long millisUntilFinished;

    public CountDownTimerCustom(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);

    }

    public void updateTickAndFinishListener(TimeTickListener tickListener) {
        mTickListener = tickListener;
    }

    public void updateFinishListner(TimeFinishListener listener) {
        mFinishListener = listener;
    }

    public long getCurrentMs() {
        return millisUntilFinished;
    }

    public int getCurrentSec() {
        return (int) millisUntilFinished / 1000;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        this.millisUntilFinished = millisUntilFinished;
        if (mTickListener != null)
            mTickListener.onTick(millisUntilFinished);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        if (mTickListener != null)
            mTickListener.onFinished();
        mFinishListener.onFinished();
    }


    public interface TimeTickListener {
        void onTick(long mMillisUntilFinished);

        void onFinished();
    }

    public interface TimeFinishListener {
        void onFinished();
    }
}
```

Comment: if it possible to provide more code for starters :)

Comment: @shareef Hi, what are you looking for?

Comment: I mean gist or repo for usage would be great

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution I used in Kotlin

```
private fun startTimer()
{
    Log.d(TAG, ":startTimer: timeString = '$timeString'")

    object : CountDownTimer(TASK_SWITCH_TIMER, 250)
    {
        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long)
        {
            val secondsUntilFinished : Long = 
            Math.ceil(millisUntilFinished.toDouble()/1000).toLong()
            val timeString = "${TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(secondsUntilFinished)}:" +
                    "%02d".format(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(secondsUntilFinished))
            Log.d(TAG, ":startTimer::CountDownTimer:millisUntilFinished = $ttlseconds")
            Log.d(TAG, ":startTimer::CountDownTimer:millisUntilFinished = $millisUntilFinished")
        }

        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        override fun onFinish()
        {
            timerTxtVw.text = "0:00"
            gameStartEndVisibility(true)
        }
    }.start()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
private void startTimer() {
    startTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            long sec = (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
 TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)));

            Log.e(TAG, "onTick: "+sec );
            tv_timer.setText(String.format("( %02d SEC )", sec));
            if(sec == 1)
            {

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tv_timer.setText("( 00 SEC )");
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }


        }

        public void onFinish() {
            tv_timer.setText("Timer finish");
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// the count down timer


 new  CountDownTimer(30000, 1000)
         {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long l) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
        
                //on finish the count down timer finsih        
                         }
          
            }
        }

    }.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Clean solution with Rx, someone might be interested in**

Extension for Numbers (Double, Float, Long, etc.):

```
fun Number.countDownTimer(tick: Long = 1, timeUnit: TimeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS): Observable<Long> {
    val count = this.toLong()
    return Observable.interval(tick, timeUnit)
        .take(count)
        .map { count - it - 1 }
}
```

Usage

```
60.countDownTimer().subscribe { textView.text = it }
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieve a cool approach for the timer with kotlin flows so you can implement this in *ViewModel*

```
    var countDownInit = 30
    fun countDownTimer() = flow<Int> {
    var time = countDownInit
    emit(time)
    while (true){
        time--
        delay(1000L)
        countDownInit = time
        emit(time)
    }
}
```

then in your activity or fragment just call this function like this

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
        lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED){
                 viewModel.countDownTimer().collect{time->
                      //and update UI 
                     //and for the finish section you can just use this
                     this.cancel()          
                 }
        }
}
```

And there is now crash or sth on the pause of the application lifecycle and always you have the latest seconds