# How to change images in imageview every n number of seconds

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview

I have made an array that has all the images in int and  i want to change those images every 3 seconds in the imageView, I have tries all the solutions I could find but was showing some error, I can't figure it out .

java file (home.java)

```
/**
* Created by sukhvir on 17/04/2015.
*/
public class home extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    ImageView MyImageView;
    int[] imageArray = { R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4, R.drawable.image5 };

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /**
         * Inflate the layout for this fragment
        */
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
    }
}
```

xml file(home.xml)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yon can simply use Thread / Timer / CountDownTimer to change the Image on Each second.

Answer (score 5):

Best option to achieve your requirement is You should use [`Timer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) to change Image each of 3 seconds as follows.

```
// Declare globally
private int position = -1;

/**
 * This timer will call each of the seconds.
 */
Timer mTimer = new Timer();
mTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // As timer is not a Main/UI thread need to do all UI task on runOnUiThread
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    // increase your position so new image will show
                position++;
                // check whether position increased to length then set it to 0
                // so it will show images in circuler
                if (position >= imageArray.length)
                    position = 0;
                // Set Image
                MyImageView.setImageResource(imageArray[position]);
            }
        });
    }
}, 0, 3000);
// where 0 is for start now and 3000 (3 second) is for interval to change image as you mentioned in question
```

Comment: the position in coming in red  , cannot resolve symbol 'position'

Comment: you should declare position as int variable globally.

Comment: the app is getting forced closed

Answer (score 0):

use a `CountDownTimer` here is how: [How to make a countdown Timer in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032003/how-to-make-a-countdown-timer-in-android)
and change the image view background inside `onFinish()`.
hope this will work out for you

Answer (score 0):

first define a runnable

```
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        changeImage(pos);
    }
};
```

Than create a handler

```
private Handler handler;
handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
```

In your changeImage method

```
private void changeImage(int pos) {
    yourImageView.setImageResource(imageArray[pos]);
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, duration);
}
```

Start and stop runnable with:

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable, duration);
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
```

I hope this'll help you. Good luck.