# Is it possible to create a database and change time every second?

Tags: android, mysql

I want to type date and hour on the database and on my android application I want to see countdown. So my database should change every second. Is it possible with mysql?

Comment: Is it that you want to set a date in your database, and then your phone should do a countdown until it reaches the date you set in your database?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for my bad English :(

Comment: Write a query and get the date from the database. Then add a CountDownTimer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032003/how-to-make-a-countdown-timer-in-android