# Scheduled timer not working

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android app and in that I have a `countdown timer` which `onFinish()` does this -

```
double initial_time = 0.0;
double countup;

public void onFinish() {
                    startTimer();
                }

         public void startTimer(){
        //Start the scheduled timer
        Log.d("hi","crash app 0");
        Early_Delay_Display.setText(R.string.Departure_Delay);
        rootView.invalidate();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(
                new java.util.TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d("hi","crash app 1" + initial_time);
                        countup = 0.0 + initial_time;
                        Log.d("hi","crash app 2" + initial_time + "---------" + countup);
                        Early_Delay_Time.setText(String.valueOf(countup));
                        rootView.invalidate();
                        initial_time = initial_time + 0.5;
                    }
                },
                1000, 30000//delay,period
        );
    }
```

Basically using this timer, I want to display 0.5,1.0,1.5 for every 30 seconds but the app crashes.

The logs are  -

```
crash app 0
crash app 1 0.0
crash app 2 0.0---------0.0
```

After this the app crashes

Comment: could u please paste the log ?

Comment: The logs are there already

Comment: He was talking about the Error Log - stacktrace ...

Comment: Call this code in background thread or use `Handler` instead.

Comment: Are you accessing GUI elements directly? `Early_Delay_Time.setText` - is it set or does it crash before?

Comment: @Fildor it crashes before Early_Delay_Time.setText

Answer (score 0):

There's special [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) in android, so you can just use it like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032003/how-to-make-a-countdown-timer-in-android)

Comment: My question is not about countdown timer. It is about the timer which is different from countdown timer. My countdown timer works well

Comment: @Samuel909 why do you do it onFinish() then? what is the point? I guess you're accessing the view, which was already destroyed: rootView

Answer (score 0):

I guess your activity is destroyed and then timer makes your app crash.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer. You can never update the UI froma thread. Instead you could do this -

```
public void startUpCounting(){
        //Start the scheduled timer
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                countup = 0.0 + initial_time;
                Log.d("hi","crash app 2" + initial_time + "---------" + countup);
                mHandler.obtainMessage(1).sendToTarget();
                initial_time = initial_time + 0.5;
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
    }

    public Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Early_Delay_Time.setText(String.valueOf(countup));
            rootView.invalidate();
        }
    };
```