# Android Studio - For loop delay with Handler Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, for-loop, delay

I am trying to set a for loop with a delay using the handler thread. But when i set up the handler thread within the for loop i cannot use the index of the for loop as it says it must be called final, however that does not work either. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Post your code here for better help...

Answer (score 1):

To `Sleep` `Thread` for while time you have to set `for loop` outside of `postDelayed` like below way. In that way you can acheive the `Index` of the `loop`.

```
final ImageButton[] all= {btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4};
Handler handler1 = new Handler();
for (int a = 1; a<= all.length ;a++) {
    handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

         @Override
         public void run() {

             //Here..
         }
         }, 1000 * a);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use CountDownTimer:

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
       //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        mTextField.setText("done!");
    }

}.start();
```

[How to make a countdown Timer in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032003/how-to-make-a-countdown-timer-in-android)

Or even like this:

```
public void animateTextView(float initialValue, float finalValue, final TextView  textview) {

    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(initialValue, finalValue);
    valueAnimator.setDuration(1500);

    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {

            textview.setText(valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue().toString());

        }
    });
    valueAnimator.start();

}
```