# How can i use countDown timer in android

Tags: android, android-timer

I want use **countDown** timer in my application and i should create such as this : 
[Click too see image](https://image.ibb.co/bJJcCa/dtjyuku.jpg)

How can i create countDownTimer such as above design?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a countdown Timer in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032003/how-to-make-a-countdown-timer-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

```
private void downTimer(){
    new CountDownTimer(120*1000,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            long second = (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60;
            long minutes = (millisUntilFinished/(1000*60)) % 60;
            textViewCountDownTimer.setText(minutes + ":" + second);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            textViewCountDownTimer.setText("Finish");
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Example of showing a 30 second countdown in a text field:

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }

    public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
    }

}.start();
```

Visit https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Comment: please see my images in my post. i want create such as this

Comment: You need to make a custom layout for that. Like in above code there is mTextFied. Start with only displaying seconds then improvise your code according to the need.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you :

https://github.com/tsuryo/Android-Countdown-Timer

```
    <com.tsuryo.androidcountdown.Counter
    android:id="@+id/counte1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:max_time_unit="DAY"
    app:text_color="#2196F3"
    app:text_size="36dp"
    app:textual_description="true"
    app:counter_font="DIGITAL_BOLD" />
```

and Java:

```
mCounter = findViewById(R.id.counter);
mCounter.setDate("2019-07-19T18:33:00"); //countdown starts
```

Comment: Hello bro, how about on a daily basis? for example the countdown will always start at 11:15AM and it will ends at 11:00AM on the following day?