# Google Maps not bringing my markers from database

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get all the markers from my database, I have them stored this way

[image]

Now, I create two arraylists of markers, one to add all those markers and then pass it to the other one in order to delete them (I'm trying to refresh the markers in realtime as they show in the map).

But I have tried this to show the markers and it seems it shows me just the first one but not iterate through all the children. Here is what I have tried:

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        mDatabase.child("usuarios").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (Marker marker : realTimeMarkers) {
                    marker.remove();
                }

                for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    MapsPojo mp = snapshot.getValue(MapsPojo.class);
                    Double latitud = mp.getLatitud();
                    Double longitud = mp.getLongitud();

                    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                    markerOptions.position(new LatLng(latitud,longitud));
                    markerOptions.snippet("ID: "+snapshot.getKey());
                    tmpRealTimeMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(markerOptions));


                }

                realTimeMarkers.clear();
                realTimeMarkers.addAll(tmpRealTimeMarkers);


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });



    }
```

where realTimeMarkers and tmpRealTimeMarkers:

```
private ArrayList<Marker> tmpRealTimeMarkers = new ArrayList<Marker>();
    private ArrayList<Marker> realTimeMarkers = new ArrayList<Marker>();
```

[image]

Also the hint is not there, I run the debugger and it seems it's not entering in my `foreach` to fetch all the latitudes and longitudes.

Comment: use `addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){` instead of `addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {`

Comment: still the same peter

Comment: i made a log, and i think its retrieving only one value -31.3703015Long-64.3575491

Comment: its working now, i think i have missplaced the lat longs in firebase, thanks peter !

Comment: i was thinking on valueeventlistener, but i think i will use a countdowntimer to refresh the dots each 10 seconds

Comment: this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032003/how-to-make-a-countdown-timer-in-android? addvalueventlistener will retrieve whenever data changes at the specific location

Comment: yes, about eventlistener , my requirement is to fetch the data every 10 seconds , so yes, i need to use the countdowntimer to call onMapReady every 10 - 20 seconds, thanks peter !

Comment: no problem! goodluck!

Comment: @Gastón: please run your questions through an English spell-checker prior to posting them. In particular, the contraction of "I am" is "I'm", with an apostrophe. The reference to yourself ("I") is always a capital letter. If you can do this for your readers, your questions will be easier to read for people who help you, as well as future readers.

Comment: Thanks for the advice , will do in the future

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

Error solved! I have placed same markers at the database and they were stacked up.