# Display the remaining time of the handler

Tags: android, handler, countdown, countdowntimer

I would like to know how to display the time remaining in my handler.
When I click a button, I run my handler for x seconds, and I want to display a countdown on the screen before the end of the handler.

Comment: create a countdown timer and set the same time as the one in your handler. Here's a thread to help you create a countdown timer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36713370/10300673

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer)

> Example of showing a 30 second countdown in a text field:

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {
     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
}.start();
```

Comment: It works fine thank you, last detail, if I put 5 seconds, it shows: 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 and 0. In the end it's 6 seconds. How to remove the 0 at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    int time = 60;  // seconds
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            time--;
            mTextView.setText(time + " seconds");
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

> It works fine thank you, last detail, if I put 5 seconds, it shows: 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 and 0. In the end it's 6 seconds.

Maxime, as I read in your comment to Thomas Mary's answer, you want to avoid getting an extra call to onTick().

You're seeing this because the [original implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/CountDownTimer.java) of CountDownTimer calls onTick() for the first time as soon as (without delay) the timer is started.

> How to remove the 0 at the end?

For this you can use this modified CountDownTimer :

```
public abstract class CountDownTimer {

private final long mMillisInFuture;
private final long mCountdownInterval;
private long mStopTimeInFuture;

private boolean mCancelled = false;

public CountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
    mMillisInFuture = millisInFuture;
    mCountdownInterval = countDownInterval;
}

public synchronized final void cancel() {
    mCancelled = true;
    mHandler.removeMessages(MSG);
}

public synchronized final CountDownTimer start() {
    mCancelled = false;
    if (mMillisInFuture <= 0) {
        onFinish();
        return this;
    }
    mStopTimeInFuture = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + mMillisInFuture;
    onTick(mMillisInFuture);
    mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(mHandler.obtainMessage(MSG), mCountdownInterval);
    return this;
}

public abstract void onTick(long millisUntilFinished);

public abstract void onFinish();

private static final int MSG = 1;

private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        synchronized (CountDownTimer.this) {
            if (mCancelled)
                return;
            final long millisLeft = mStopTimeInFuture - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            if (millisLeft <= 0) {
                onFinish();
            } else {
                onTick(millisLeft);
                sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(MSG), mCountdownInterval);
            }
        }
    }
};
}
```

Note that you might need to adjust your implementation in onTick() method accordingly.