# How to make countdowntimer for android?

Tags: android, kotlin

im new at coding, i dont know even basics but

I need make somekind 20 seconds countdown timer and i didin't found any working tutorials.

I tried my best but always some error came up.

Comment: you can use `CountDownTimer` in Android

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a countdown timer in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032003/how-to-make-a-countdown-timer-in-android)

Comment: You can just use coroutines and delay for 20_000 milliseconds, till then coroutine will be suspended meaning it will be detached from thread. It is less expensive resource than a standalone thread.

Answer (score 1):

pass `time` in milliseconds.
var countDownTimer: CountDownTimer? = null //declare it as global variable

```
fun startCountDown(time: Long) {
        countDownTimer = object: CountDownTimer(time,1000){
          override fun onFinish() {
            Timber.v("Countdown: Finished")
            visibility = View.GONE
          }

          override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            Timber.v("Countdown: $millisUntilFinished")
            visibility = View.VISIBLE
            updateTimeView(millisUntilFinished)
          }

        }
        countDownTimer?.start()
      }
```

For example:

`startCountDown(30000)`, will countdown from 30 to 0.

Note:
Don't forget to stop the timer when your app stops:

```
override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    countDownTimer?.cancel()
  }
```