# Use CountDown Timer to call static FinishAffinity method to close the app

Tags: c#, android, countdowntimer

I have implemented a countdown class in my app and i intend to close this app when the `OnFinish()` method in the class is called in `OnCreate` after `future` parameter expires.
I tried to create an instance of my activity class and then the method `FinishAffinity` but it didnt work, Here is my code...

```
 public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        private GLSurfaceView glView;
        public static Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        public static bool g = false;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
         MyTimer myTimer = new MyTimer(10000, 1000);
            myTimer.Start();
            myTimer.OnTick(1000);
            myTimer.OnFinish();
        }
    }
  public class MyTimer : CountDownTimer
    {
        private int a = 10;

        public MyTimer(long future, long interval) : base(future, interval)
        {
        }

        public override void OnFinish()
        {
       //There is an error for accessing the method directly so i tried instantiating the class and then calling the Finish Method
        MainActivity y= new MainActivity();
        //Call method to finish all underlying activities
          y.FinishAffinity();
        }

        public override void OnTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            int u = a--;
            MyToast.MakeText(Application.Context, "this app will close in " + u + " " + "seconds", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }
```

The `FinishAffinity` method in the `OnFinish` method is not working so is there any way to call this from outside the class without creating a `static to non-static reference error`

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of the `MainActivity` in the `onFinish()`
i.e. `MainActivity y = new MainActivity();` which is not right.
It should be simply `MainActivity.this.finishAffinity()` if the Countdown class is a nested inner class.

Otherwise, you can simple create a `MainActivity` parameter in your Countdown class' constructor & call `mainActivity.finishAffinity()`

Comment: The first solution you suggested is throwing a null object reference and then  for the second, the app freezes on launch, is there something like ```(MainActivity)GetActivity)```kind of thing i can use

Comment: I don't have much experience in `C#`, but I guess you can check a basic implementation of a CountDown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10032406/6819340

Comment: Okay thanks for the advise anyways, am leaving an upvote

Comment: Can i create an intent and send to a broadcast receiver which i will then use to close the app?

Answer (score 0):

Declare your `programid` in the class and make it static so you can access it from the CountDownTimer class and then call `killprocess(int y)` like this

```
 public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        private GLSurfaceView glView;
        public static Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        public static bool g = false;
        public static int ourProgramid;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
         MyTimer myTimer = new MyTimer(10000, 1000);
            myTimer.Start();
            myTimer.OnTick(1000);
            myTimer.OnFinish();
            ourProgramid=Android.OS.Process.MyId();
        }
    }
  public class MyTimer : CountDownTimer
    {
        private int a = 10;

        public MyTimer(long future, long interval) : base(future, interval)
        {
        }

        public override void OnFinish()
        {
       //There is an error for accessing the method directly so i tried instantiating the class and then calling the Finish Method
       MainActivity y= new MainActivity();
        //Use killprocess to exit app instead
          Android.Os.Process.KillProcess(MainActivity.ourProgramId);
        }

        public override void OnTick(long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            int u = a--;
            MyToast.MakeText(Application.Context, "this app will close in " + u + " " + "seconds", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }
```