# How can I make the Chronometer and Timer restart after 15 minutes?

Tags: java, android, loops, timer, chronometer

I made a button that starts a Chronometer and I want to make the Chronometer restart after 15 minutes (to be looping). I am new to coding and I don't know how to manage that .

The code:

```
btPlay.setOnClickListener(v -> {

        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        chronometer.start();

    });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032003/how-to-make-a-countdown-timer-in-android this may be a solution for you

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
btPlay.setOnClickListener(v -> {

      startCounting=true;

    });

myHandle = new Handler();
 myHandle.post(new Runnable() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
        myHandle.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        if(startCounting){
           //put your counting code here.
        }
     }

});
```

the void run function will get called every 1 second. you can add you code inside the run method.

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'startCounting'. How can I fix it?

Comment: startCounting is a boolean. You have to declare it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on Android?.
If so, then you can try using the handler class to run repeated tasks.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to implement it.